# Setting a timeout policy on SLRequest?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making requests to the Twitter/Facebook API's using iOS Social Framework and SLRequest objects- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/SLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I would like to add a timeout to the SLRequest similar to NSURLRequest's timeoutInterval.  Is there any way to do this?  Not seeing anything in the docs that make this doable, but I would think there has to be a way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* create a "`NSMutableRequest`" with all the elements & fields from the "`NSURLRequest`" returned by the [`[SLRequest preparedURLRequest]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/SLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SLRequest/preparedURLRequest) method.

Once you construct your NSMutableRequest, it's trivial to set a timeout value.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for mentioning its trivial - I didn't realize there is a default timeout on NSURLRequests. I probably don't even need to set it on SLRequest, but I'll test to make sure it has one! Thanks!